# Unexpected Character after line continuation while implementing regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-group

I am trying to search a file in a folder using regex, but when i try to pass the regex in a variable like

```
file_to_search = re.search('Weekly' +(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})$ + 'Scores.xlsx')
```

The file pattern I am trying to search is

Weekly 02.28.2018 Scores.xlsx

Weekly 03.05.2018 Scores.xlsx

As of now I dont care if the file is:

Weekly 99.99.9999 Scores.xlsx

But I get the below error pointing at the end of the line.

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.
```

file_to_search = re.search('Weekly' +\d{2}\d{2}\d{4}+ 'Scores.xlsx')

```
                                                          ^
```

Comment: `(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})$` is not a valid expression. Regular expressions are written as strings in Python. You specifically left it out of your string.

Comment: waht about `startswith()` and `endswith()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `re.search` needs a pattern and a text. You left one of them out.
- Python does not have a literal syntax for regular expressions, which means all regular expressions in Python need to be strings.
- You probably didn't mean `.xlsx`.
- You need to escape the extension dot. (You do not need to escape the dot in the date, since it is inside square brackets, a character class.)
- You need to account for space. A literal space works okay here; if it's possible it might be a tab or something `\s` would be preferable.
- I use raw string literal `r'...'` so I can write `\d` instead of `\\d` etc.

All together now:

```
match = re.search(r'^Weekly \d{2}[/.-]\d{2}[/.-]\d{4} Scores\.xslx$', file_to_test)
```

Comment: "`re.search` needs a pattern and a text.". So, it is the string where you are hoping to find the pattern. EDIT: You said "I am trying to search a file in a folder using regex", and that, in conjunction with your comment just now, worries me that you might not know what regexps do. They find text in strings. They don't find files on your disk. To find files, you might use `os.listdir`, `os.walk`, `glob` module, and I'm sure I'm leaving some things out; once you have a list of potential candidates you can use regex to filter them out more precisely.

Comment: So the way I am implementing this is , defining a variable something like this   file_to_search = re.search(r'^Weekly \d{2}[/.-]\d{2}[/.-]\d{4} Scores\.xlsx$')           def search_file():
        for file in os.listdir(source):
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, file_to_search):
                        return True
        return False
if search_file():
        print('File exists')
else:
        print('File not found')

Comment: Comments are superbad for more than one line of code, and that goes double for Python which has indent syntax. `fnmatch` matching and `regexp` matching are two different kinds of matching - you can't give `fnmatch` a regular expression, if that's what you were trying to do. And even so, compiled regular expressions are created by `needle = re.compile(regex_string)`, then you can use it as `needle.search(haystack)`; `re.search(regex_string, haystack)` is a shortcut that does this together.

Comment: In your example, `for file in os.listdir(...)` is correct; after that, you can do `if re.search(regex_string, file):`, _or_ you can do `fnmatch.fnmatch(fnmatch_string, file)` (in which case you don't need `re.search`). The patterns of `fnmatch` are described at the top of the [corresponding doc page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html), and are _not related to regular expressions at all_ (except by the fact that they are both used for text matching).

Comment: I am fine with the rest of the functions. The error that I am getting right now is <<<< search() takes at least 2 arguments >>>>, so I just want to know what is the second argument I need to pass when declaring the regex in the variable?

Comment: Again, as you apparently missed it: `variable = re.search(regex_string)` _is not "declaring regex in the variable"_. To put a regex in the variable, you do `variable = re.compile(regex_string)`. Not `search`. `compile`. Because `search` _searches_. Through the second argument. Which I already said in the first two sentences of my first comment under this question. And also the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks re.compile works for passing regex to a variable

Comment: But now I get a new error that says                                                               TypeError: object of type '_sre.SRE_Pattern' has no len()

Comment: This is a separate error, and I have no idea what you wrote to make it happen; please post a new question (possibly with a link to this one), and make sure to include the code that generates that error. Many misunderstandings in this post might have been avoided if you had posted in the question the code that you eventually put in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life simpler:

```
>>> import re
>>> matcher = re.compile( r'Weekly \d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d Scores.xlsx' )
>>> a = '''The file pattern I am trying to search is
... 
... Weekly 02.28.2018 Scores.xlsx
... 
... Weekly 03.05.2018 Scores.xlsx
... 
... As of now I dont care if the file is:
... 
... Weekly 99.99.9999 Scores.xlsx
... 
... But I get the below error pointing at the end of the line.'''
>>> matcher.findall( a )
['Weekly 02.28.2018 Scores.xlsx', 'Weekly 03.05.2018 Scores.xlsx', 'Weekly 99.99.9999 Scores.xlsx']
>>>
```

I hope this answers your question =)

Of if you want to work with files:

```
>>> filenames = matcher.findall( a )
>>> filenames.append( 'somefile.txt' )
>>> for f in filenames : print f, matcher.match( f ) is not None
... 
Weekly 02.28.2018 Scores.xlsx True
Weekly 03.05.2018 Scores.xlsx True
Weekly 99.99.9999 Scores.xlsx True
somefile.txt False
>>>
```